# Calling a function with uninitalized struct variable as a parameter doesn't produce a warning

Tags: c++, makefile, coverity

I have the following code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Pair{
  int x;
  int y;
}Pair;

void dumFun(Pair p){}

int main() {
    Pair p;
    
    if (0){
      p = {1,2};
    }
    
    dumFun(p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled the code, I expected to get a warning for the line with `dumFun(p)` since I'm calling a function with an uninitialized variable.
What I actually want is that my Makefile will give me warning for uninitialized scalar variable issues that I see with the tool Coverity.

Tried to use flag -Wall and I thought it shows warnings for unused variables usage as this - but it doesn't.

Is there any flag to use on a Makefile that will show me warning for the line I wrote above?

Comment: `-Wall` does not actually show all warnings. Use `-Wextra` to show warnings about uninitialized variables. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Actually you need `-Wextra`. `-Wall` only complains about uninitialized scalars but not about uninitialized structs. Check [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/rP65dzz4h). OTOH my Microsoft compiler issues even an error: `error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'p' used`

Comment: `-Wall` is misleadingly named. It actually means "all common warnings" not "all warnings"

Comment: @vll: `-Wextra` doesn't work for me: it shows `unused parameter` warning for the line `void dumFun(Pair p){}` , but I wanted it to show a warning for the line `dumFun(p)`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in C++ you don't need to do the `typedef struct ...` dance. `struct Pair { int x; int y; };` works just fine. In C the handling of names is different, and you do the typedef so you don't have to write `struct Pair` every place you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell the compiler, but at least in Clang there is no warning that would catch this. `-Weverything` shows all possible warnings, and you can use it to find the specific parameter needed to trigger each warning. [Demonstration with -Weverything](https://www.godbolt.org/z/r5Y98zrK5) shows no warnings.

I did not find a suitable parameter in GCC either.